# Implementation approach for android student app

Tags: android, database

I would like to implement an android application for students where they  would have to register or login using an email or registration number (undecided) and be able to view their course details (module marks & taken modules) & also timetables. A single page application for the admin interface would be implemented so that the admin can add, edit and delete students from respective courses using the email or registration number that was used upon sign up. What technologies would I need to implement such an application apart from android studio, a database and web-server?

Comment: Stack overflow is not about helping you choose technologies but rather about solving specific programming problems. Try and develop your app and if you run into a specific issue come back to us. As is this question is way to broad

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is a very broad question here are some links to help:

1) https://developer.android.com/guide/ The android developer guide, has a lot of great reading.

2) https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/ building your first app tutorial

3) https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide this is the getting started guide to developing android apps, these days it even contains an app architecture approach